# How to Uninstall .exe setups Installed programs showing in control panel using Python

Tags: python, wmi, uninstallation

I gone through this code but this code works for only MSI installer but I wanted to Uninstall other than msi packages.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
print ("Searching for matching products...")

for product in c.Win32_Product(Name = "Product Name"):
    print ("Uninstalling" + product.Name + "...")
    result = product.Uninstall()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Win32_Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class only list the software installed with the Windows installer (MSI), to list and uninstall another software you can read the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` windows registry key and check the value of the `UninstallString` value of each entry.